# texas hold um no limit

Tags: rules

IN a texas hold no limit game, my question is this, a player raises, the next player to act pushes all chips across the line and says I call all in. with hands off chips are all chips comitted to all in,

Comment: This is very unclear as to what your question is. Can you please rework this so we can try help you as best we can?

Comment: "I call all in" is ambiguous, so it has to be interpreted in context. If there's only the two players, I might rule it a call, and force the player to take back any amount over what's needed to call, but ruling it an all-in raise might also be reasonable if I had more knowledge of the players' habits and skill levels. If there were a third player in the pot, I would probably rule it an all-in raise, and let the chips stay. If there were just the two players, he shoves in all his chips, and the first player immediately says "call", then it's definitely an all-in raise.

Comment: The question makes no sense, you need to explain it more.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker It's not ambiguous at all. The verbal statement is clearly a call. The only thing that matters is whether the player pushed the chips over the line before or after making the verbal statement.

Answer (score 1):

If the stack of chips being pushed is smaller than the amount needed to call, then there is no ambiguity: it is a short all-in.  Otherwise "I call" and "all in" mean different things, so the statement "I call all in" is ambiguous, and must be interpreted in context. It matters in what order the actions took place: did he shove all the chips in, remove his hand, and then speak (in which case chips speak and his announcement doesn't matter), or did he speak before or while moving chips? Did he pause between saying "I call" and "all in"? Did he move his chips with more than one motion? It also might make a difference whether or not there are more than two players involved. And perhaps player habits might apply--is this a new player who is perhaps not fluent in the jargon, and everyone at the table knew his intent was to raise all-in?

In most cases, as a floorman, I would likely rule that the player has made an all-in raise, and let the chips stay. But if I thought that the player was shooting an angle by trying to see a reaction to the word "call" before saying "all in", then I would rule it a call--unless the player acting next announces "call" after the move, then I would rule it an all-in. Likewise, if they are head up, and the words "I call" happened before the chip motion, and the opponent wants me to rule it a call, then it's a call (since the player's actions were unclear and perhaps unethical, I would tend to rule in favor of his opponent).